# I am able to fetch the books of a user profiles, but i need books cover image as well to show on my website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have built a new website in php and i am allowing users to signup using facebook. I am fetching all the information like books, movies, location, travels, checkins etc. I get all the information, but i dont get the cover images with the data.

```
            $request = new FacebookRequest(
             $session,
             'GET',
             '/me',
             array(
                  'fields' => 'id,first_name,last_name,age_range,birthday,bio,education,email,about,gender,religion,relationship_status,hometown,music,books'
                )
            );
            $response = $request->execute();
```

I have seen many websites which are fetching above information with cover images. I am not sure how they are doing it, if they are using some other api to fetch cover images or something else.

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API call would get you the cover pic, if there is one:

```
/me/books?fields=cover
```

Or in one call:

```
/me?fields=books{cover}
```

...which means, you just need to replace "books" with "books{cover}" in your fields parameter.